# What is Apple Restriction on using user contact data to create user registration in an app

Tags: iphone, ios

what restrictions are there in pulling user contact data out to complete user info in an iphone.   Does there exist a restriction on association of device id to email that disallows this.  I want to know if there is anyway to pull the contact info out of the contact list and allow the user to use this existing data to fill register with my app?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to allow the user to use *this existing data* to fill the register with your app... there is no way for your app to do the same without the user permision...

simple as that, sorry